# Select a specific iFrame that has multiple instances of the same name

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

My problem is I have 3 defined iFrames on the page I am trying to work on.  They are all named the following:

```
<iframe class="col-51" height="560" src="https://attendee.gototraining.com/embed/886b2/catalog/40xxxx bgColor=ffffff" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe class="col-51" height="560" src="https://attendee.gototraining.com/embed/886b2/catalog/37xxxx bgColor=ffffff" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe class="col-51" height="560" src="https://attendee.gototraining.com/embed/886b2/catalog/46xxxx bgColor=ffffff" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have tried to driver.switchTo.frame command but it only sees index 0 which I assume is the first frame listed here.  If I select this first frame I don't get an error at runtime, however I still cannot see any elements inside the frame.  I get "cannot find element" issue.  I cant even select the 2nd or 3rd frame with switchTo using either a located I make or index 1 or 2.

I have also tried making a List involving all tagnames of iframe.  I get back only 1 result.  Again, I see 3 here.  And again, even when I choose the first one I still cannot see any elements inside the frame using conventional means.

What am I missing here?

Also please note I have put x's in for the pathway because of privacy concerns.

Here is a capture of what happens if I choose another index other than 0:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: 1
Command duration or timeout: 62 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1PV0EPA', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath locator and identify a frame by partial `src` link:

```
void switchToIframe(int catalogId)
{
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // don't get trapped in iframes
    driver.switchTo().frame(
        driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'catalog/" + catalogId + "')]"));
}
```

use it like:

```
switchToIframe(40); // frame 1
switchToIframe(36); // frame 2
switchToIframe(46); // frame 3
```

you may also need to wait for frames to load before switching to them

Comment: Ok I gave this a try and am getting no such element exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to resolve the iframes as WebElements by their XPaths.  Code snippet below stubs out the test case, you'll need to determine the xpaths to each of your iframes and fill the strings in, but I think this should be close.

```
    private static final By FRAME_PATH_1 = By.xpath("");
    private static final By FRAME_PATH_2 = By.xpath("");
    private static final By FRAME_PATH_3 = By.xpath("");

    private void traverseFrames(WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        WebElement frame1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(FRAME_PATH_1));
        WebElement frame2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(FRAME_PATH_2));
        WebElement frame3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(FRAME_PATH_3));

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame1));
        System.out.println("in Frame 1");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame2));
        System.out.println("in Frame 2");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame3));
        System.out.println("in Frame 3");

    }
```

XPaths are not great for maintainability if you expect the page contents to change, but it may get you closer to what you're looking for.  I use the Firepath extension for Firebug to help resolve xpaths.

Best of Luck